# Preventing IIS from keeping a file lock on a SQLite database file

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, iis, asp-classic, odbc

We have a legacy web application written in Classic ASP that currently uses an MS Access database as its data store. Interaction with the database occurs via the Jet OleDB provider:

```
Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=database.mdb
```

As is the case with most web applications, CRUD operations are performed on the database on a regular basis.

The application connects to the database, carries out an `insert`, `update`, `delete` or `select` statement then closes the connection. Immediately after the connection is closed, we are able to **rename** or **move** the MS Access `.mdb` file with impunity. We have taken advantage of this behaviour for many years - it's necessary for our use case and it has served us well.

For various reasons, we are in the process of replacing the MS Access database with SQLite 3. We connect to the SQLite version via ODBC.

Interaction with the SQLite database happens just like it did previously, i.e connect to the database, issue the SQL command, close the connection.

The problem is that the SQLite database file remains locked for 60 seconds after the connection is closed. This prevents us from renaming or moving the database file because it's highly likely that another connection occurs within that 60 seconds and so the file appears to be permanently locked.

We created a minimal page in Classic ASP to illustrate the behaviour:

```
Dim connectionString: connectionString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;FKSupport=0;NoCreat=1;Database=database.sqlite"

Dim con : Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open connectionString

' Issue some CRUD commands here

con.Close
Set con = Nothing
Response.Write("We are here!!!!!")
```

In order to ascertain what is causing the lock, we built a `VBScript` file (using the same SQLite connection string shown above) then we ran that from the command line (therefore IIS is not involved at all.)

In that situation, after connecting, issuing any `CRUD` commands and then closing the database, the `SQLite` file was immediately accessible. So we concluded that somehow IIS 7.5 (or more precisely `W3WP.exe`) is holding some kind of lock on the SQLite file. In fact, if we stop the App Pool for the website, the lock on the file is immediately released.

The code for the `VBScript` file is as follows:

```
Dim connectionString: connectionString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;FKSupport=0;NoCreat=1;Database=database.sqlite"

Dim con : Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open connectionString

' Issue some CRUD commands here

WScript.Echo "Press [ENTER] to continue..."

' Read dummy input. This call will not return until [ENTER] is pressed.
WScript.StdIn.ReadLine

WScript.Echo "Done."

con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

Is there some kind of setting in IIS that we can utilise that will allow us to manipulate the SQLite database just as we currently do with MS Access?

Comment: If it worked before with the MSAccess DB, how do you come to the conclusion that IIS is at fault? It's more likely the SQLite driver is the cause of the behaviour, not IIS.

Comment: @Lankymart I've edited my question to hopefully make it clearer that when connecting to SQLite from inside a VBScript file does not cause a 60 second lock on the file. But when connecting to SQLite inside a Classic ASP file does lock the file for 60 seconds. The same driver and connection string are used in both cases.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing a `conn.Close` but not following it up with a `Set conn = Nothing`

Comment: Could be something to do with connection pooling, although for the SQLite  driver you are using, pooling is disabled by default. Maybe IIS is just doing it's own thing. Found this link that claims IIS is only releasing ODBC connections after 60 seconds: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/ODBC-connection-from-ASP-remains-for-60-seconds

Comment: @GordThompson We are in fact issuing a `Set conn = Nothing` command. I edited the question to show the code.

Comment: @mrstebo excellent find, that seems highly likely according to this [10. Q. How do I clear out the connections in the pool?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/169470/info-frequently-asked-questions-about-odbc-connection-pooling).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've revisited this approximately a year after posting the original question because a colleague actually discovered the solution that worked for us and maybe it will be of help to others.

The solution that worked is to make some changes to the registry. It's nothing to do with the [CH Werner SQLIte ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/). In fact we had an email conversation with CH Werner himself and he confirmed that the driver does not affect the locking of the database as we described it.

The solution is to make the following changes to the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{c8b522cb-5cf3-11ce-ade5-00aa0044773d}]
@="MSDASQL"
"OLEDB_SERVICES"=dword:fffffffe
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{c8b522cb-5cf3-11ce-ade5-00aa0044773d}]
@="MSDASQL"
"OLEDB_SERVICES"=dword:fffffffe
```

If you place the registry changes described above into a file with **.reg** file extension you will be able to double-click it in windows explorer to make the changes.

Once the registry has these settings, `IIS` will **not** hold a lock on the `SQLite` database file for 60 seconds after the connection is closed.

Hopefully this will help others that come across this problem.

Comment: Wow, those are very specific registry keys. Happy to hear you have finally found the solution 

Comment: Hi mate, hope you're well. Yeh, Nick S came across the solution on a MySql forum of all things. It's been working in production for 6 months now. Just kept forgetting to come back here and post the solution.

Answer (score 2):

With the [CH Werner SQLite ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) you can't turn off connection pooling. There is code in the driver that handles the `SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING` attribute, but that attribute is never used. This means that it will be using connection pooling by default.

Stopping IIS keeping a lock on the database would involve modifying the DLL to include a **ConnectionPooling=True/False** or **CPTimeout=n** so that we could send the appropriate values to the `SQLSetEnvAttr` function.

Comment: @Simon you should up-vote this great investigative work!

Comment: @Lankymart, good point, I have just upvoted it. Just so you know, mrstebo actually sits 2 desks away from me. He's working on the same project :)

Comment: @SimonLomax still they found the answer, might be worth noting that in the answer but changes nothing for me. If others come across this problem it will still be helpful.